# How to make slider to width 100% on the page?

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

I use the default slider in Open Cart: `Slideshow > Home Page` that has settings in admin panel.

How can I show it on full page by width?

When I set width, height in setting, I get scaled image with white tapes on the top and bottom borders image. When I tried to set width, height as image has, I get also wrong view.

Default image has size: `3863x1145px`

So. I need to show image on thw full width.

This is example: goo.gl/xUeEPwcontent_copyCopy short URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default OC slider is set to fixed dimensions via settings in admin panel.

You need to install and use different [OC extension](https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension&filter_search=full%20width%20slider).